# Central limit theorem with different variance

Tags: central-limit-theorem

Let $\{ X_n, n\geq 1 \}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with

$P(X_n=n^{\lambda})=P(X_n=-n^{\lambda})=\frac{1}{2}$ where $0<\lambda<\infty$

Show that the central limit theorem is applicable to this sequence.

I calculate the $E(X_n)=0$, $Var(X_n)=n^{2\lambda}$, but I really don't understand the question, How so I show the "applicable"?

Answer (score 1):

Check if [Lindeberg's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) holds for your sequence. If it is satisfied, then the CLT applies.

Comment: Thank you so much, at the first, I only know the kolmogorov theorem, but it is not helpful.